# Why does my list prints output this way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
sum = []

for count in range(1000):
    if count % 3 == 0:
        sum.append(count)
        print (sum)
```

The code above prints all the numbers divisible by 3. The output is:

```
[0]
[0, 3]
[0, 3, 6]
[0, 3, 6, 9]
...
```

How can I get it to be just one list of all the numbers (like [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15,...]) without repeating each number?

Comment: Unindent the `print` line so it's not inside the `for` loop.

Comment: "all the primes of 3" - all the whats of 3? Why do you think 5 is in there?

Comment: This code doesn't print out all the "primes" of 3.  This prints out numbers that are divisible by 3.  Actually, "all primes of 3" is a contradiction to what a prime number is.  A prime number is only divisible by 1 and itself.  That statement suggests that there is more than one factor that can divide into 3.

Answer (score 2):

just put the print (sum) out of the indentation of the for loop

```
sum = []

for count in range(1000):
    if count % 3 == 0:
        sum.append(count)

print (sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comp will do what you want and avoid using variable names like `sum` that shadow `builtin` names:

```
summed = [count for count in range(1000) if count % 3 == 0]
```